# On the number of Mobius $\mu =0$ numbers less than a given number.

Tags: riemann-zeta

How many of the composite numbers are multiples of squares:

Let $C(n) =$ all composite numbers $\le n$

Let $\mu_0(n) =$ the number of integers $\le n$ with a value of $\mu =0$

$${\mu_0(n)  \over C(n)}  \thicksim (??) $$

Comment: Integers with $\mu \ne 0$ are said to be [squarefree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer).  It is a "well-known" result that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n-\mu_0(n)}{n} =  \frac{6}{\pi^2}$$  And of course $C(n)/n \to 1$, so your limit is $1 - 6/\pi^2$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you. It's the inverse of the basel problem?

Comment: Yes, see the Distribution section at the Wikipedia link I gave.